# Overridden properties from superclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, inheritance, properties

I have a superclass of UIViewController - `MasterViewController` which declares a property called `itemsViewController`. This declares a method called from the MasterViewController, and is wired up via a storyboard in IB.

I have a subclass of MasterViewController which redeclares this property as a specific iPad version, but I can't access the redeclared property from the parent class.

**MasterViewController**

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ItemsViewController *itemsViewController;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize itemsViewController;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
// I can access itemsViewController in viewDidLoad.

}
@end
```

**MasterViewController_iPad**

```
@interface MasterViewController_iPad : MasterViewController {
    IBOutlet ItemsViewController_iPad *_itemsViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ItemsViewController_iPad *itemsViewController;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController_iPad
@synthesize itemsViewController = _itemsViewController;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// when I call super viewDidLoad,  itemsViewController is nil, as though the property hasn't been overriden
// _itemsViewController is not nil in viewDidLoad.
}
@end
```

Am I misunderstanding the way property inheritance works in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the type signature of a method when you override a superclass method.

`MasterViewController` has these methods:

```
(void)setItemsViewController:(ItemsViewController *)foo
(ItemsViewController *)itemsViewController
```

But you're trying to give `MasterViewController_iPad` these methods:

```
(void)setItemsViewController:(ItemsViewController_iPad *)foo
(ItemsViewController_iPad *)itemsViewController
```

Which you can't do: you can't overload the same method name but have different types for the arguments.

If `ItemsViewController_iPad` is a subclass of `ItemsViewController`, a quick solution would be to keep the same signature as in `MasterViewController` but simply use an `ItemsViewController_iPad` when you set the property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use category if you'd like to override property. Here is example:

I have `PDFFileChooserViewController` with `PDFFileModel` and `PDFFilesDataSource` and some logic related to this properties.

```
@class PDFFileModel, PDFFilesDataSource;
@interface PDFFileChooserViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) PDFFileModel* selectedModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PDFFilesDataSource*dataSource;

@end
```

Then I'd like to add specific ViewController for choosing files from Dropbox but my model have some additional fields for example `dropboxPath` and my `DropboxDataSource` gets files using another way. So I decided to create category and override this properties:

```
#import "PDFFileChooserViewController.h"


@class DropboxFileModel,DropboxDataSource;

@interface DropboxViewController : PDFFileChooserViewController
@end

@interface DropboxViewController (ModelCategory)
@property(nonatomic, strong) DropboxFileModel* selectedModel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) DropboxDataSource* dataSource;
@end
```

Notice that this category will be visible inside DropboxViewController only where I can manipulate with that properties but another classes see only super class interface